# How could I stop a multiprocess from inside a QT window?

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm trying to use some multiprocessing in my program and I'm facing an issue.
I launch a multiprocessing, which makes something not important here, by pressing a button in a Qt window. I'm not able to stop it from an other button. So far, I've got this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing


def mp_worker(a):
    for i in range(a):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('keep going :' +str(i))
    return

def Multifunc(k):
    for i in range(k):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target= mp_worker , args=(10,))
        p.start()



class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QHBoxLayout()

        self.Param_box = QGroupBox(" ")
        self.layout_Param_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Button_Threads = QPushButton('Run Threads')
        self.Button_stop = QPushButton('stop Threads')
        self.layout_Param_box.addWidget(self.Button_Threads)
        self.layout_Param_box.addWidget(self.Button_stop)
        self.Param_box.setLayout(self.layout_Param_box)

        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.Param_box)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

        self.Button_Threads.clicked.connect(self.RunThreads)
        self.Button_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    def RunThreads(self):
        Multifunc(10)
        return

    def stop(self):
        # How stop the multi process ?
        return


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So the `RunThreads` function runs the multiprocessing and the `stop` function should stop the multiprocessing, but as python is inside my worker, I cannot stop the multiprocessing from the Qt class. I don't understand what should be my `stop`function. Should I use kind of SIGNAL to perform the multiprocessing stop? Or should I pass some variables to `Multifunc`? I'm a bit confuse about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop the processes you must have the Process object, for them we will make the following modifications:

1. We will return the list of Process

---

```
def Multifunc(k):
    ps = []
    for i in range(k):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target= mp_worker , args=(10,))
        ps.append(p)
        p.start()
    return ps
```

2. We save the list of objects in an attribute of the class.

---

```
def RunThreads(self):
    self.ps = Multifunc(10)
    return
```

3. We execute the terminate function for each process:

---

```
def stop(self):
    # How stop the multi process ?
    for p in self.ps:
        p.terminate()
```

**Complete code:**

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing


def mp_worker(a):
    for i in range(a):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('keep going :' +str(i))
    return

def Multifunc(k):
    ps = []
    for i in range(k):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target= mp_worker , args=(10,))
        ps.append(p)
        p.start()
    return ps



class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QHBoxLayout()

        self.Param_box = QGroupBox(" ")
        self.layout_Param_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Button_Threads = QPushButton('Run Threads')
        self.Button_stop = QPushButton('stop Threads')
        self.layout_Param_box.addWidget(self.Button_Threads)
        self.layout_Param_box.addWidget(self.Button_stop)
        self.Param_box.setLayout(self.layout_Param_box)

        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.Param_box)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

        self.Button_Threads.clicked.connect(self.RunThreads)
        self.Button_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    def RunThreads(self):
        self.ps = Multifunc(10)
        return

    def stop(self):
        # How stop the multi process ?
        for p in self.ps:
            p.terminate()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Handsome. It seems pretty obvious now I have a solution :)
Thanks you.